# EditText steals focus from other EditTexts inside ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a stand-alone `EditText` and a `ListView`. Each item in the ListView also has two `EditText` fields. When I touch inside the `ListView` `EditText`, the stand-alone `EditText` steals the focus. This makes it impossible to edit any of the `ListView` `EditText` fields.

[image: <code>Name</code> steals the focus from the other <code>TextView</code> elements inside the <code>ListView</code>]

*`Name` steals the focus from the other `TextView` elements inside the `ListView`*

Here is the activity's XML, containing the stand-alone `EditText` and the `ListView`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
  android:orientation = "vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dip" >

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="@string/name"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editblindschedule_name"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="5"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="text" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_editblindschedule"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the `ListView` row XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/editblindschedule_round"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editblindschedule_small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/small"
    android:ems="4"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:text="@string/integer_zero"
    android:gravity="center" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editblindschedule_big"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/big"
    android:ems="4"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:text="@string/integer_zero"
    android:gravity="center" />

  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/editblindschedule_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:checked="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Java code

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_blind_schedule);

    ...

    adapter = new BlindAdapter(this, blindSchedule.getBlindLevels());
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_editblindschedule);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And finally, the adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_editblindschedule, parent, false);

      if (!creating) {  // Set default values.

        TextView round = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.editblindschedule_round);
        EditText small = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editblindschedule_small);
        EditText big = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editblindschedule_big);

        round.setText("" + (position + 1));
        small.setText("" + blindLevels.get(position).getSmallBlind());
        big.setText("" + blindLevels.get(position).getBigBlind());
      }

      return row;
    }
```

Comment: can the `ListView` get focus? The `checkboxes` work? Also, are you sure you are not doing anything weird with the focuses(?!) in your `Java` code?

Comment: The CheckBoxes work (can be checked or unchecked). What actually happens with the nested `TextEdit`s is that they gain focus for 500ms and then the cursor moves to the other `TextEdit`. I'll post my Java code.

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this issue ? I'm having the exact same issue and cannot find a way to fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to put android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the activity in the manifest. This was the only change necessary for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like it but after digging `ListView` code I ended up by overriding the `getFocusedChild()` method and returning null as all other trials of flag combinations didn't get to a satisfactory solution.
Even if `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` works adjusting pan leads to too much artifacts in my layout.

**Beware** overriding that method may lead to other unwanted behaviours so use it and test it comprehensively in all android versions you support and may be call super instead of returning null for android versions that does not/will have this problem.